# Throw an error in Laravel (not eloquent)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my package I perform a check on a user id:

```
//check
if(!$this->checkId($id)) //error
```

If this fails I need to throw an error as the method in my package will fail to work and I need to inform the user.

Please note, this is not a eloquent query so I do not need any find or fail methods.

How can I do this in laravel?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answer, but I would throw an exception from `checkId()` method - since either check passes or fails (and throws exception).

```
class CheckIdException extends Exception
{
}

class WhateverClass
{
    public function checkId($id)
    {
        // do the check
        $passes = ....

        if (! $passes) {
            throw new CheckIdException('CheckId() failed');
        }

        return true;
    }
}


// somewhere in the app code
try {
    $this->checkId($id);
} catch (CheckIdException $e) {
    return Response::json(['error' => 'checkId', 'message' => 'meaningul error description']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return Response::json(['error' => 'UnknownError', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
}

// yay, ID check passes! Continue!
```

Answer (score 0):

...so just throw an error?

```
if(!$this->checkId($id)) //error
{ 
    App::abort(500, 'CheckId() failed');
}
```

or

```
if(!$this->checkId($id)) //error
{ 
    throw new Exception("CheckId() failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, which one would be recommended? My scenario is, the app provides an id to my package, I then do something to the id, if this fails, what should I do? Abort or throw an exception?

Comment: If you abort the app - you force the app to fail. But if you throw an exception, you give the *opportunity* for the person using your code to catch the exception and do something about it. If they do nothing, it will abort the app anyway.